# How to show exactly 4 numbers after decimal point without rounding in Python?

Tags: python, decimal-point

I want to calculate square root of numbers and print them with exactly 4 numbers after decimal point without rounding. 
This code rounds the numbers

```
num="%.4f" % num
```

and this one doesn't show 1.0000 or numbers like this.

```
num=math.floor(num * 10000)/10000
```

Comment: Why not *combine* those two methods?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option if you wish printing / just showing the 4 numbers after decimal point:

```
 num = 0.553252
'{:.4f}'.format(num)
```

You can find more information on presenting strings / values here - 
https://pyformat.info/#number

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> num = 5.12129
>>> num = f'{num:.5f}'[:-1]
>>> num
'5.1212'
```

Comment: Try `5.121299`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the number to a string, then use string manipulation:

```
def numberWithoutRounding(num, precision=4):
    [beforeDecimal, afterDecimal] = str(num).split('.')
    return beforeDecimal + '.' + afterDecimal[0:precision]
```

```
>>> numberWithoutRounding(1.43219)
'1.4321'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them into string. Here's a way -

```py
num = str(0.5532523).split('.')
ans = '%s.%s' % (num[0], num[1][:4])
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the significant digits to the left of the decimal point, truncate it with ‘int’ and them move them back.

```
num = float (int (num * 10000) / 10000)
print (num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
tedad=int(input())
adadlist=[]
rishe=[]
for i in range(0,tedad):
    adadlist.append(int(input()))
    n='%.4f'%float(int(math.sqrt(adadlist[i])*10000)/10000)
    rishe.append(n)
for x in range(0,len(rishe)):
    print(rishe[x])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please add context so we can learn from it. Also, bots will flag it for removal if there is no context provided by the answer. Enjoy SO.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import math

list = []

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    digits = float(input())
    x = math.sqrt(digits)
    formula = '{:.4f}'.format(float(int(x * 10000) / 10000))
    list.append(formula)

for v in list:
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> k = 4.35889321
>>> x,y = map(str,str(k).split("."))
>>> print(x+"."+(y[:4]))
4.3588
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the following code.

```
import math
from math import sqrt
n = int(input())
square = []

for i in range(n):
    i = int(input())
    x = math.sqrt(i)
    z = ('%.15f' % x)
    square.append(z)

for j in square:
    print(j[:-11])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

It works in this way
from math import sqrt

number_input = int(input())

sqrts= []

for i in range(0, number_input):

```
sqrts.append(sqrt(float(input())))
```

for i in sqrts:

```
a = int(i * 10000)/10000
print(f"{a:.4f}")
```